# Reverse for 'X' not found. 'X' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Django Framework

Tags: python, html, css, django

I 'm new to Django concept

I have 3 files for this issue.

I have a urls.py  in my project file call firt_website with the following code:

```
"""firt_website URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from pages import urls

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls', namespace='home')),
    path('portfolio/', include('pages.urls', namespace='portfolio')),
    path('experience/', include('pages.urls', namespace='experience')),
    path('education/', include('pages.urls', namespace='education')),

]
```

I have the Navbar HTML that will be included in an index page HTML as {% extends 'navbar.html' %} : the files contains :

```
 <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container">
            <ul class="u-custom-font u-font-titillium-web u-nav u-spacing-30 u-unstyled u-nav-1"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-2 u-border-active-white u-border-hover-custom-color-2 u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-white u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-text-white" href="Acceuil.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-2 u-border-active-white u-border-hover-custom-color-2 u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-white u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-text-white" href="Experience.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Experience</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-2 u-border-active-white u-border-hover-custom-color-2 u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-white u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-text-white" href="Education.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Study</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-2 u-border-active-white u-border-hover-custom-color-2 u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-white u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-text-white" href="Portfolio.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Portfolio</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-border-2 u-border-active-white u-border-hover-custom-color-2 u-border-no-left u-border-no-right u-border-no-top u-button-style u-nav-link u-text-active-white u-text-hover-custom-color-2 u-text-white" href="Acceuil.html#sec-1120" data-page-id="134427998" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Contact</a>
</li></ul>
          </div>
          <div class="u-custom-menu u-nav-container-collapse">
            <div class="u-align-center u-black u-container-style u-inner-container-layout u-opacity u-opacity-95 u-sidenav">
              <div class="u-sidenav-overflow">
                <div class="u-menu-close"></div>
                <ul class="u-align-center u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-nav-2"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Acceuil.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'experience' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Experience</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Education.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Study</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Portfolio.html" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Portfolio</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="Acceuil.html#sec-1120" data-page-id="134427998" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Contact</a>
</li></ul>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Then the pages/urls.py that is the folder project_app called pages :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'pages'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='homepage'),
    path('education/', views.education, name='education'),
    path('experience/', views.experience, name='experience'),
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
]
```

Here are my views files containing the  link to the HTML docs

```
rom django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import ContactForm

# Create your views here.


def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")


def education(request):
    return render(request, 'Education.html')


def experience(request):
    return render(request, 'Experience.html')


def portfolio(request):
    return render(request, 'Portfolio.html')
```

I have been struggling to create a navbar that works whether I am on an index page and would like to go a portfolio page and then go back to the index page after being on portfolio pages

I have tried all type of Django code and versions and not many shows how to do a navbar ...

do you know why it does work to do the {% url 'experience' %} ??
what can I do and the easiest options?

[error Django reverse match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZVmK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specified `app_name = 'main'`, that means you need to prefix the name of the view with the `app_name`, so:

```
{% url 'main:experience' %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,  It works , however when I click on it now it shows the following error :                            


Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Experience.html
Using the URLconf defined in firt_website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='homepage']
education/ [name='education']
experience/ [name='experience']
portfolio/ [name='portfolio']
portfolio/
experience/
education/
The current path, Experience.html, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: @yedx_1_10: that's because you wrote `hrefs` like `href="Experience.html"`. but the URL is simply `experience/` so *without* the `.html`, you should replace this with `href="{% url 'main:experience %}"` as well such that these are easily adapted when you change url patterns.